# Draft.js how to represent list of items?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs, draft-js-plugins

In order to create image carousel, I thought creating nested blocks as following

- image_carousels

  - image
  - image
  - image

Then I found draft.js doesn't support nested blocks. (https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/143 they say draft.js is flat)

But on the other hand, there's UL/OL and LI , that's like group and element structure.

Is there a way to group elements/components/blocks so that we can render the whole + individual (such as we render carousel with individual images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draft.js doesn’t actually support `ul`/`ol` and `li` as separate blocks – these are just implemented as `ordered-list-item` and `unordered-list-item` blocks, stored as a flat list in the editor.

The nesting is "faked" by having those blocks’ `depth` set to values above 0, and using wrappers to wrap sequences of those blocks into a parent element. See the docs: [Advanced topics – Custom block wrappers](https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-custom-block-render-map#custom-block-wrappers)
.

---

If it works for you, you could follow a similar model and have a single block type `image-carousel-item`, that contains the contents of each "slide", then use a wrapper to render carousels with multiple items however you want, both in the editor and when exporting HTML.